# local db отображение данных в таблице на form2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Я делаю реляционную базу данных. Когда вытаскиваю на form1 из источника данных таблицу основную и связанную с ней, то в связанной отображаются данные по соответствующему ключу. То есть в компании с id=1 показываются те, кому проставлен id_company=1. Но такой фокус при таком же переносе на вторую форму не срабатывает. Как сделать чтобы это работало как надо.
Если можно, то второй вопрос. А как автоматически заполнять связную колонку. Чтобы не вспоминать какой код у какой компании, а чтобы по выделенной компании в одной таблице автоматически этот код появлялся у вновь забиваемого сотрудника?

**Обновление**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [Surname] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [phone_number] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [Address] NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
    [id_Company] INT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_ToCompany] FOREIGN KEY ([id_Company]) REFERENCES [Company]([id])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [Company_name] NVARCHAR(50) NULL
)
```

Форма 1. В коде всё стандартно и всё создано автоматически кроме обработчика нажатия на строку таблицы. Остальное сюда не лезет.

```
private void companyDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 Form=new Form2();
    Form.Show();
    Form.Show();
}
```

Ну и два грида на форме. Один компании  другой персонал связанный.

Вторая форма полностью код создан автоматически там bindingNavigator и Grid.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "dBCompanyDataSet.Person". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
    this.personTableAdapter.Fill(this.dBCompanyDataSet.Person);

}
```

Если речь о sql, то запрос тоже стандартный `SELECT Id, Name, Surname, phone_number, Address, id_Company FROM dbo.Person`. Вчера пытался добавить новый с whis, но результат тот же.

Comment: 1. Нужна структура таблиц. 2. Необходим код. Из того что вы написали можно нафантазировать много всего.

Comment: Кстати обработчик тоже срабатывает раз на десятый((

Comment: Для описания проблемы используйте область, где вы задали вопрос, там есть ссылка "править". Со структурой все понятно. Представьте код, который вы используете для загрузки данных в DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

1. Заполнение DataGridView:

   ```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();

   SqlConnection dataBaseConnection = new SqlConnection(connect);
   SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id, Name, Surname, phone_number, Address, id_Company FROM dbo.Person", dataBaseConnection);
   dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Person"); 
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Person"];
   ```

Как вариант можно использовать: [DataGridView.DataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)

2. Для того чтобы сохранить запись в таблице "Person" вам нужно чтобы в таблице "Company" уже присутствовала та запись, на которую она будет ссылаться. В другом случае вы не сохраните данные. Так что автоматики тут не выйдет.
3. И еще совет, старайтесь придерживаться best practicies по именованию: таблиц, переменных, методов и т.д.[Вот вам вариант!](https://habrahabr.ru/post/26077/)

**UPD:**

Ответ на комментарий:

В эту таблицу вы записываете id компании, так как она связана с "Company" посредством FK.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Person (Name, Surname, phone_number, Address, id_company) VALUE ('Вася', 'Пупкин', '12345678', 'ул. Петрова 13', 1)
```

Где 1 - это id компании в таблице "Company".

А для того чтобы получить связанные данные

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Surname, p.phone_number, p.Address, cmp.Name  FROM dbo.Person p Left Join dbo.Company cmp ON p.id_company = cmp.id
```

Ну и следовательно, для того, чтобы добавить значения в таблицу "Company", нужно писать

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Company (Name) VALUE ('Рога и Копыта')
```

Comment: ПО ПОВОДУ П.2  то записи в таблице набил. Я правильно понимаю, что id_company в таблице person всегда придётся ставить ручками?

Comment: По комментарию делаю update в ответе на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем. Нашёл обходной путь добавлением на форму комбобоксов, где выбираются записи. И автоматика и, в моём случае, такая конструкция может быть даже удобнее.
Возник новый вопрос. А как сделать чтобы в одном из столбцов можно было сохранять ссылки на документы, или сами документы. То есть по человечески, чтобы справа в ячейках отображалась кнопка с многоточием, на которую жмёшь, открывается проводник, где выбирается файл и его расположение сохранилось в ячейке